# How to leave minor div after major div on the same line?

Tags: html, css

I am scaling several divs and have one that is larger than the others in width and height, the other divs that are after this one are too low, not aligned on the same line.

Note: execute the code below on **full page**, Follows the code:

```css
body {
    background-color: #2E5173;
}

div {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 240px;
    height: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12)!important;
}

.big {
    width: 508px;
    height: 508px;
}
```

```html
<div class="">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="big">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="">this div is very low</div>
 <div class="">this div is very low</div>
```

The code above looks like this:

[image]

I need it to look like this:

[image]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do this using CSS grid:

```css
.container {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit,240px); /* The width */
  grid-auto-rows:250px; /* The height */
  grid-auto-flow:dense; /*This is the important property*/
  /* The margin */
  grid-gap:20px;
  padding:10px;
}
.container div {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #2E5173;
}

.big {
  grid-column:span 2; /* Take twice the width*/
  grid-row:span 2; /* Take twice the height*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="big">&nbsp;</div>
  <div>this div is very low</div>
  <div>this div is very low</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS Grid can provide you with great control of your layouts and is not super complicated. A few of the resources I've used in the last are listed below:

```
www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp
learncssgrid.com
css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid
```

CSS Grid also works well with media queries if you need the page to be responsive.